# A shim between bottom headset cup and bearing

Tags: headset, shim

I ended up in a situation in which my new fork with an integrated crown race imposes lower headset bearing (1.5" 45deg) stack restriction, i.e. I need an additional 1.5mm of bearing height so the fork doesn't rub lower headset cup (bonded to CF tube, by the way).

I see two ways to alleviate the issue:

1. Grind a bit of headset lower cup so the fork clears. It's aluminium and hanging part that rubs the fork serves no structural purpose, at least that's what I think.
2. Use a shim between lower cup and a bearing. See the CAD drawing for details. I reckon the support of cup from top (45deg surface) and outside (54mm inner diameter) should be enough, after all it's the same mechanism that keeps the bearing in place. But to my surprise, I failed to find such a product!

[image: shim CAD drawing, not actual size]

So, the question(s): is the shim approach a viable solution? If no, why exactly? If yes, can I buy one?

**Update:** in perfect scenario, I want to use the shim with another, less tall but lighter bearing I already own. I do not want to purchase a taller bearing.

Here's a fork crown photo:
[image: fork crown]
A the tight situation:
[image]

**Update 2:** as promised, the bottom headset cup:
[image: bottom headset cup]
The tall bearing height is 8mm, the less tall lightweight bearing is 7mm.

**Update 3:** the 2.5mm shim looks too thick even for a 7mm bearing, the gap is ~2.4mm:
[image: 2.5mm shim]
[image: 2.4mm gap with 2.5mm shim and 7mm bearing]

Comment: A picture of the lower headset cup and fork crown may be helpful here.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus added the fork photo. Maybe I'll add the cup tomorrow too (I'd have to press the bearing out and that's a bother.), but you might as well just imagine a regular CF front tube with an integrated 1.5" 45deg cup.

Comment: You may need a thicker bearing. Cane Creek has a bunch of helpful charts to help with proper bearing selection.

Comment: @BillSkiCO yeah, that's an option. I've emailed CC to get info on AER bearing height, but I very much doubt it will be taller than the bearing from photos.

Comment: What fork is this? This is a really weird situation and I believe it's the fork that's the root problem. Usually they have more tapered area than this. Putting a shim in the frame will make it challenging to keep the bearing seat as precise as it's supposed to be. It may lead to some combination of problems with noises and not being able to adjust the headset well.

Comment: @NathanKnutson let's say this fork comes from a completely different frameset. Yes, I am mix-matching components.

Comment: Did the fork you used before had a integrated crown race and is crown race of the new fork compatible with your headset bearing? At leat on my different headset's I can't just switch the crown race. So a shim/adapter to mimick the correct crown race would be the way to go here.

Comment: @nollak both old/current crown races are for 1.5" 45° bearing and work fine.

Comment: @Klaster_1 then I would just go ahead and use a shim.

Comment: @nollak that's the plan, but while I design and order the part machining I'd like to get feedback about the idea. Maybe someone tried that? Or knows where to buy the shim?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that you are missing something on your assembly. There is this one ring that you should put on your fork, that makes contact with the bearing. Take a look at your old fork, it's probably there, sometime is easy to miss even for people whom been working on bikes their whole life. See the link, it's the pressing ring https://www.dhresource.com/webp/m/0x0s/f2-albu-g5-M00-08-79-rBVaI1j-AwyAMj1eAANBoQTxJYg145.jpg/mountain-bike-sealed-bearing-headset-bicycle-cycling-wrist-tapered-group-bowl-group-bicycle-parts-head-tube-fork-gub-g-800-+b.jpg

Comment: It's the silver one top right corner

Comment: @dmb the link doesn't work, but you probably meant the crown race. As I already said before, [my new fork has an integrated crown race](https://i.imgur.com/TvcV0uG.jpg) (the left one).

Comment: @Klaster_1 Sorry about that, that's what we call it here. Anyways have you tryed using the old crown race with your new fork? Your old fork looks wider(at the crown race) than your new one. Do you have a caliper? Measure just over the chamfer on your new fork and old fork.

Comment: If you do use a shim, I suggest one of the fancy high-strength plastic materials. Doing it with aluminum sounds very creaky to me. Honestly thought the shim route sounds like a lot of work for an outcome that could have a lot of potential pitfalls and you won't know until you get there. A little bit of micro-play introduced by the presence of the shim may be very perceptible once the fork is leveraging on it.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I've added the cup photo.

Comment: The 1.5mm shim fits perfectly, I'll post a report in a month or two as an answer. If anyone wants, I've got a bunch of shims left.

Comment: @Klaster_1 how's it going?  Ready to post a followup ?

Comment: @Criggie I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The custom shim works**, I settled with a ~1.4mm option, this was the minimal thickness machinist agreed to make, he said "it would bend in your pocket otherwise". After properly preloading the headset bearings I did not notice any play during pedaling efforts or when applying front disc brake during ~200km the bike made since assembly. That's not much distance, so if anything happens and I survive I'll update the answer.

Apparently, some people experience the same problem.

**To get your own shims**, find a local machinist and use the blueprint from the question, adjust thickness as needed. My shims were made from a 2024 aluminium alloy plate. The outer diameter tolerance should be in the ballpark of +0mm -0.03mm, the rest doesn't matter.

Comment: Seem to be attracting a few followon posts.  Could you extend this accepted answer at all?  Like where to get the shims and anything else relevant?

Comment: @Criggie that's exactly what second paragraph says. I don't have any shims left for sale and no longer have access to person responsible for manufacturing. Maybe you have something more concrete to suggest?

Comment: @Criggie thanks for the edit, something as simple didn't even come to my mind!

Answer (score 1):

I bought a bike from Van Nicholas in the Netherlands. It's the Skeiron road bike. The frame came with the fork so I would guess it should have been machined together for bearings and all without a problem. They sent 2 shims same as you described but I can't see why 2. The fork fits nicely, very close, but nicely with the Cane Creek headset bearing in the crown. The top of the headset was a different matter however, the headset cover did rub the headtube  and one of those shims placed between the bearing and the headtube race made for a prefect fit. Almost a year of riding and no issues at all.

Comment: That's interesting, can you add a shim photo and maybe shop contact info?